# Tensorflow: create tf.NodeDef() and set attributes

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create a new node and set its attributes.

For example printing one of the graph nodes I see that its attributes are:

```
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
```

I can create a node like:

```
node = tf.NodeDef(name='MyConstTensor', op='Const',
                   attr={'value': tf.AttrValue(tensor=tensor_proto),
                         'dtype': tf.AttrValue(type=dt)})
```

but how to add `key: "T"` atribute? i.e. what should be inside `tf.AttrValue` in this case?

Looking at [attr_value.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.proto) I have tried:

```
node = tf.NodeDef()
node.name = 'MySub'
node.op = 'Sub'
node.input.extend(['MyConstTensor', 'conv2'])
node.attr["key"].s = 'T' # TypeError: 'T' has type str, but expected one of: bytes
```

**UPDATE:**

I figured out that in Tensorflow it should be written like:

```
node.attr["T"].type = b'float32'
```

But this gives an error:

> TypeError: b'float32' has type bytes, but expected one of: int, long

And I'm not sure which int value corresponds to float32.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.proto#L23

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value.proto#L35

Comment: You can have a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/616 for how to save/load a graph.

Comment: @knh190 How it's related?

Comment: @knh190 I know how to save the graph, the question is about how to add attribute at `tf.NodeDef` creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By trial and error I fugire out that it's just:

```
node.attr["T"].type = 1 # to set type to float32
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing T as a byte:

```
node.attr["key"].s = b'T'
```

If you would like to pass more characters try the bytearray class.

In the protobuf definition of AttrValue s is defined as bytes not string. The [Protobuf manual](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#scalar) states that this should be a string in python but your error suggests it is more like a byte array.

Comment: @mrgloom From  attr_value.proto I can not deduct what definition DataType has. Can you look it up and use those definitions to set .type

Answer (score 0):

No need for trial and error:

```py
node.attr["T"].type = tf.float32.as_datatype_enum
```

Overall, you may see all datatype codes within the sources at [tensorflow/c/tf_datatype.h](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/tf_datatype.h) (see `typedef enum TF_DataType`)